# Left CTRL key is not working after updating to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, asus

After I updated to Ubuntu 18.04 my left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is not working neither is the shortcut using <kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>fn</kbd> to turn on/off touchpad. I have Asus K55UQ.

Answer (score 0):

Try Resetting keyboard shortcuts in Settings > Devices > Keyboard.

Comment: No such setting